# I somehow got 2000 reputation out of nowhere and now I own somebody else's questions?

Tags: support, bug, merge-accounts

[image]

[image]

I never wrote these questions nor the comments in the questions. What is going on?

[image]

Comment: A comment on an answer of that question leads to [this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253060), which reveals [the original OP's UID](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/21502948/anm) on chat.stackoverflow.com. However, their profile [cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21502948/anm).

Comment: If you did not merge accounts, send the Community Management team a message using the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact).

Comment: @SamuelLiew I couldnt have since I do not even know the account. I will do this

Comment: I was confused why your rep is now 439 but most of that 2,000 is association bonuses for other sites

Comment: I thought I've seen everything o_O

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It seems like another person's account was somehow merged into yours.

If you did not merge accounts, send the Community Management (staff) team a message using the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) as only developers can perform an unmerge.

Comment: how does this happen though? I just assume that a merge requires some manually verified degree of consent from both accounts?

Comment: @starball presumably as a result of someone who had received manually verified consent, manually executing whatever database operation, and fat-fingering a user ID or something.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it seems merges aren't necessarily manual. The system automatically merges accounts in certain cases: [Stop automatically merging accounts without asking the users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307348/stop-automatically-merging-accounts-without-asking-the-users) (MSE)