# How can I get my wife's account back?

Tags: support, accounts

I'm guessing my account and my wife's account were merged since we share the same IP address. She recently tried to log into her account, entered her e-mail and password and logged into my account. What can we do? In general, her account is clean and she can create another one, but what can we do to prevent them from being merged?

Comment: Your wife should use the [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https://stackoverflow.co) form, use the Other option and explain the case. There is nothing we can do here.

Comment: You and your wife aren't sharing the same browser, right? Because that is an unsupported use-case.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283328/multiple-accounts-in-the-same-household

Comment: Perhaps this could happened. Why is that an unsupported use-case?

Comment: Because there is only one set of authentication cookies and from there all successful logins are considered to be the same network-account, doing an auto-merge.  I have a write-up on how [universal login works for a single user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312956/158100). There is too much magic going  on to make that work for separate accounts.

Comment: Some browsers have support for having multiple profiles, so if you want to share the same browser you can have separate profiles for both of you. Although it might just be easier to use separate browsers since it could be easy to forget to change the profile.

Comment: Or, at least, have separate logins for the same device, as then each user has their own set of user settings and data (including cookies).

Comment: Related: *[I somehow got 2000 reputation out of nowhere and now I own somebody else's questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425927)*. That question's poster still has two meta posts linked with them, even though one of them was posted by a different person.

Answer (score 11):

A community manager did this. There's no moderator requests to point to, but I noticed your reputation dropped afterward. It's probable that your wife was voting for your account.

There's two possible issues here

1. You answered your wife's question (or vice versa). That's a type of vote fraud. I can't tell if that was the case on some of your posts [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74812453). It's acceptable to answer your own question, which is a good reason to merge accounts.
2. She voted on your posts (or vice versa).

Make sure you understand the [rules for sockpuppets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388985/2370483) going forward. If your wife behaves like a sockpuppet, she will be treated like one.

Only a community manager can fix this. Use the [Contact us form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https://stackoverflow.co) to appeal the action.

Comment: *"If your wife behaves like a sockpuppet, she will be treated like one."*. Wow. Don't let Twitter read that one!